# Apt-get & software updates failure: Unmet dependencies with kernel package, no diskspace?

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

Using ubuntu 14.04 LTS with GNOME Classic desktop i can't install the latest upgrades. Most important update is ubuntu base linux kernel updates.
Error message:

> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
>   since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the
>   following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

doing that i get the following output:

```
(Reading database ... 689243 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_i386.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic (3.13.0-57.95) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic/include/config/inet6/ah.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic/include/config/inet6/ah.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

allthough none of the partitions is 100% used:

```
/dev/sda10      9,1G  560M  8,1G   7% /var
/dev/sda6       9,1G  1,1G  7,6G  13% /home
/dev/sda7       922M  474M  386M  56% /boot
/dev/sda8       9,1G   21M  8,6G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda9       9,1G  7,8G  779M  92% /usr
```

Allthough the Disk Usage analyzer shows 100% Usage on / Directory.
Trying to remove or purge older kernels isn't possible because unmet dependencies.

Please help me scince setting up a new system is no option right now. Thanks.

Comment: P.S.:  current Kernel is 3.13.0-57-generic, oldest is 3.13.0-35

Comment: Log-in to the newest working kernel in your system and then remove all the old kernals by `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")` then try updating the system

Comment: Thank you. Logged in to 3.13.0-57, Output as follow:
'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic but it is not installed'
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: try this: `sudo apt-get purge linux-generic`

Comment: Output: 'You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-57-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
'

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried all this. Is it possible that the sources.list file is corrupted? Btw Before this occured i also installed a PC-Version of Sailfish OS for VBox. I encountered the Problem while trying to update Vbox using the ubuntu software center - it sait that the installed software is corrupted. –